# How do I convert from type to generic?

Tags: c#, generics

hy there!

given is this class:

```
public static class FooClass<TFoo>
{
    public static TFoo FooMethod(object source)
    {
        // implementation goes here
    }
}
```

now i want to create this class:

```
public static class FooClass
{
    public static object FooMethod(object source, Type fooType)
    {
        var classType = typeof (FooClass<>).MakeGenericType(fooType);
        var methodInfo = classType.GetMethod("FooMethod", new[]
        {
            typeof (object)
        });
        // WHAT NOW?!
    }
}
```

also to mention:

- there are overloads of `FooMethod` in `FooClass<TFoo>`, but i only want to give access to mentioned overload (signature is matching - except paramterNames)
- returnType `object` would be succifient
- i cannot make `FooMethod` in `FooClass` generic - it should be an "oldstyle" interface, as it will be used from reflection-code

Comment: Do you want to convert or cast it?

Comment: @bobby ?? ... i want to execute the method :) ... casting, converting done somewhere else...

Comment: In that case I completely missed the meaning of your question, sorry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like:

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static object FooMethod(object source, Type fooType)
    {
        return typeof(Foo<>).MakeGenericType(fooType)
            .GetMethod("FooMethod").Invoke(null, new object[] { source });
    }
}
```

**however** - this reflection can be slow in a tight loop; if you are doing this lots, I would be tempted to reverse the dependency, so the generic code calls into the non-generic code:

```
public static class Foo<TFoo>
{
    public static TFoo FooMethod(object source)
    {
        return (TFoo)Foo.FooMethod(source, typeof(TFoo));
    }
}
```

(with the implementation in the non-generic version)

Comment: i know about the slowdown :) it's just about an optional interface, where the consumer knows about the slowdown

Comment: ahh ... just another question: does reflection support `out`?

Comment: @Andreas yes; create the `object[]` for the arguments, and store it in a variable (passing this variable into the `Invoke` method). After the call, check the array - any `out`/`ref` values should have been updated.