# How do I call a static property of a generic class with reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I have a class (that I cannot modify) that simplifies to this:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    public static string MyProperty {
         get {return "Method: " + typeof( T ).ToString(); }
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to call this method when I only have a `System.Type`

**i.e.**

```
Type myType = typeof( string );
string myProp = ???;
Console.WriteLinte( myMethodResult );
```

**What I've Tried:**

I know how to instantiate generics classes with reflection:

```
Type myGenericClass = typeof(Foo<>).MakeGenericType( 
    new Type[] { typeof(string) }
);
object o = Activator.CreateInstance( myGenericClass );
```

However, is this proper to instantiate a class since I am using the static property? How do I gain access to the method if I can't compile time cast it? (System.Object does not have a definition for `static MyProperty`)

**Edit**
I realized after posting, the class I'm working with is a property, not a method. I apologize for the confusion

Comment: it's more or less like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215729/how-do-i-convert-from-type-to-generic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method is static, so you don't need an instance of an object. You could directly invoke it:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    public static string MyMethod()
    {
        return "Method: " + typeof(T).ToString();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Type myType = typeof(string);
        var fooType = typeof(Foo<>).MakeGenericType(myType);
        var myMethod = fooType.GetMethod("MyMethod", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        var result = (string)myMethod.Invoke(null, null);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you don't need an instance to call a static method:

```
Type myGenericClass = typeof(Foo<>).MakeGenericType( 
    new Type[] { typeof(string) }
);
```

Is OK... then, simply:

```
var property = myGenericClass.GetProperty("MyProperty").GetGetMethod().Invoke(null, new object[0]);
```

should do it.

Answer (score 3):

```
typeof(Foo<>)
    .MakeGenericType(typeof(string))
    .GetProperty("MyProperty")
    .GetValue(null, null);
```

Comment: This may work for when I know I'll be using system.string, but I don't know the type at compile time

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

```
typeof(Foo<string>)
    .GetProperty("MyProperty")
    .GetGetMethod()
    .Invoke(null, new object[0]);
```